# Dynamic sorting with nullable column

Tags: linq, sorting, dynamic

I am writing dynamic sorting with lambda expression as below:

```
string sortColumn = imageFilterType == 1 ? "CreatedDate" : "AbuseCount";
var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Items), typeof(Items).ToString());
Expression propConvExp = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(paramExp, sortColumn), typeof(object));
var sortExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Items, object>>(propConvExp, paramExp);
```

Above I am creating dynamic sort column and I am applying this sortexpression in bellow query:

```
var items = _db.Items.AsQueryable()
                     .AsExpandable()
                     .OrderByDescending(sortExp)
                     .Where(predicate)
                     .Select(x => x)
                     .Join(_db.Users, i => i.UserId, u => u.UserID, (i, u) => new
                        {
                            i,
                            FullName = u.UserType == 1 ? u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName : u.CompanyName,
                            u.UserType,
                            u.UserName
                        })
                    .ToList()
                    .Skip(pageIndex)
                    .Take(pageSize);
```

I have 2 columns in input by which I have to sort data one is CreatedDate and another is Abusecount. I have to apply sorting with one column among both of them. but as I am trying to run above code I am getting error:

> "Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Since in my database both column is of nullable type thatswhy I am getting this problem. Is anyone have solution of this problem? I don't want to change in DB. I have to solve it from fron end only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's much simplier:

```
var items = _db.Items.AsQueryable()
                 .AsExpandable();
if (imageFilterType == 1)
   items=items.OrderByDescending(a=>a.CreatedDate);
else
   items=items.OrderByDescending(a=>a.AbuseCount);

items=items.Where(predicate)
                 .Select(x => x)
                 .Join(_db.Users, i => i.UserId, u => u.UserID, (i, u) => new
                    {
                        i,
                        FullName = u.UserType == 1 ? u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName : u.CompanyName,
                        u.UserType,
                        u.UserName
                    })
                 .Skip(pageIndex)
                 .Take(pageSize)
                 .ToList();
```